Make element pop out & change background color without shifting text css
The main idea is that the class .pop-out transforms the code to change background, pop up off the screen a bit (scale & shadow), etc. The only problem is, there is no padding on my original element to the left and right, so it would look very weird when I pop it out without adding more padding as part of the transition.
When I do add padding, it shifts the text as there is now a different amount of horizontal space. I cannot add padding before hand, or the text will be misaligned. How can I fix this?
I currently have the following code:


* {
  box-sizing: border-box; 
}

.pop-out {
    position: relative;
    transition: transform 0.2s ease-in-out, box-shadow 0.2s ease-in-out, background-color 0.2s ease-in-out, border-radius 0.2s ease-in-out;

    &:hover {
        cursor: pointer;
        background-color: white !important; 
        box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
        transform: scale(1.1);
        border-radius: 10px;
        padding-left: 1rem; 
        padding-right: 1rem;
    }
}

#wrapper {
  margin-left: 50px;
  display: flex; 
  justify-content: center; 
}

#my-element {
  background-color: gray;
  width: 200px; 
  flex: 0 0 auto; 
  
}
<div id="wrapper">
  <div class="pop-out" id="my-element">
    My element. lipsumlipsum      </div>
</div>




Please include your code on StackOverflow as code snippet.

By 'misaligned' do you mean that actually you don't want the text to move at all, but for some padding to appear to its left hand side?

@yogi No, the problem is not that the padding isn't being animated. It's that because you're adding any padding at all, the text inside shifts.

@AHaworth In my actual web-page, there is a paragraph & a title, I want the paragraph to pop out on hover. I cannot add padding before as then the title and paragraph won't be left-aligned.

OK, so although the text gets bigger, the left hand side of the leftmost character must remain in the same position. Have I got that right?

@AHaworth Sorry, I'm doing a bad job of explaining -- the alignment when the text is actually being hovered upon does not matter. I am saying I cannot add extra padding beforehand because it would cause misalignment, which is causing the whole problem. When I add padding upon hover, some of the text no longer fits and shifts. I have updated my example to show what is happening better.

i think you should read this first How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example

dose this answer your question?

pleas provide a visual of the desired output here to enhance clarity

@MarkSchultheiss How can I provide a visual if I am trying to figure out the CSS to create the visual?

A handrawn sketch of what the before and after should look like would be helpful.

@MikeSmith so you have two accounts? be careful with that ref https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/104903/multiple-accounts-in-stack-overflow

@MarkSchultheiss A handdrawn examples is hard given that my question is regarding an animation -- bountyScript's answer is essentially what I want to do except for the fact that on hover, when it gets a shadow, you can see that there is no padding. I want there to be some space between the border and the text, but due to alignment issues I cannot place a padding before hand. The problem is if you add padding after, the text suddenly has less space and thus shifts weirdly. I tried adding a border instead of padding but that did not work either.

The only major solution I see is to somehow change the positioning to absolute while keeping the rest of the elements fixed in place...

To ensure the text doesn't 'move' when scaling so that things stay aligned you could have the whole background color, 'padding', border radius and shadow on a before pseudo element which has absolute positioning.
Also, when doing the scale transform have the origin at top right of the element so the text doesn't shift (if that is what is required) in terms of its left hand position so things are still aligned with any title.
I've put 'padding in quotes here because this snippet creates the effect of padding by increasing the pseudo element's width.


<style>
  * {
    box-sizing: border-box;
  }
  
  .pop-out {
    transform-origin: top left;
    position: relative;
    transition: transform 0.2s ease-in-out, box-shadow 0.2s ease-in-out, background-color 0.2s ease-in-out, border-radius 0.2s ease-in-out;
    &:hover {
      cursor: pointer;
      transform: scale(1.1);
    }
  }
  
  #wrapper {
    margin-left: 50px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
  }
  
  #my-element {
    width: 200px;
    flex: 0 0 auto;
    position: relative;
  }
  
  #my-element::before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: gray;
    transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
    border-radius: 0px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    transform-origin: center center;
    z-index: -1;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
  }
  
  #my-element:hover::before {
    width: calc(100% + 2rem);
    background: white;
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    border-radius: 10px;
  }
</style>
<div id="wrapper">
  <div class="pop-out" id="my-element">
    My element.
  </div>
</div>






* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.pop-out {
  position: relative;
  transition: transform 0.2s ease-in-out, box-shadow 0.2s ease-in-out, background-color 0.2s ease-in-out, border-radius 0.2s ease-in-out;
  background-color: gray;
  width: 200px;
  display: inline-block;
}


/* Create a pseudo-element to handle padding-like space on hover */

.pop-out::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  transition: padding 0.2s ease-in-out;
  z-index: -1;
  /* Put it behind the main content */
}

.pop-out:hover::before {
  padding-left: 1rem;
  padding-right: 1rem;
}

.pop-out:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: white !important;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  transform: scale(1.1);
  border-radius: 10px;
}

#wrapper {
  margin-left: 50px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
<div id="wrapper">
  <div class="pop-out" id="my-element">
    My element.
  </div>
</div>




Pseudo-element ::before: This creates an invisible element that takes up space and will expand its width (or padding) when hovered. This prevents the actual content from shifting.

Z-index: Ensures the pseudo-element doesn’t cover the actual content of your element.

Transition: The transition still works, creating the effect of padding growing, but since it's on a pseudo-element, the content inside the div stays static.



Not 100% sure on your requirement as it is hard to describe a visual but perhaps all you need is to add white-space: nowrap; to your hover


* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.pop-out {
  position: relative;
  transition: transform 0.2s ease-in-out, box-shadow 0.2s ease-in-out, background-color 0.2s ease-in-out, border-radius 0.2s ease-in-out;
  &:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
    background-color: white !important;
    box-shadow: 0 0 1.6667rem rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    /* transform: scale(1.1);*/
    border-radius: 10px;
    padding-left: 1rem;
    padding-right: 1rem;
    margin-left: -1.9rem;
    white-space: nowrap;
  }
}

#wrapper {
  margin-left: 50px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

#my-element {
  background-color: gray;
  width: 200px;
  flex: 0 0 auto;
}
<div id="wrapper">
  <div class="pop-out" id="my-element">My element. lipsumlipsum</div>
</div>




In your solution, the text is shifting upon hover, which is what I am trying to avoid.

Using Chrome I do not see a shift, just the border/padding change in the same location

I also commented out the transform and the padding which you had set - perhaps ugly visually but just changes the color on the background and adds the shadow border

Yeah that was the problem I was trying to solve  If I don't add padding then it looks pretty ugly with the shadow and color change as the text is so close to the border.

Could you describe why before/after absolutely positioned pseudo element doesn’t help? Thanks.

I added a left margin given latest comment on question by OP.

Use min-width instead of width so that the transformed element can get wider and fit the text in one line:


* {
  box-sizing: border-box; 
}

.pop-out {
    position: relative;
    transition: transform 0.2s ease-in-out, box-shadow 0.2s ease-in-out, background-color 0.2s ease-in-out, border-radius 0.2s ease-in-out;

    &:hover {
        cursor: pointer;
        background-color: white !important; 
        box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
        transform: scale(1.1);
        border-radius: 10px;
        padding-left: 1rem; 
        padding-right: 1rem;
    }
}

#wrapper {
  margin-left: 50px;
  display: flex; 
  justify-content: center; 
}

#my-element {
  background-color: gray;
  min-width: 200px; 
  flex: 0 0 auto; 
  
}
<div id="wrapper">
  <div class="pop-out" id="my-element">
    My element. lipsumlipsum      </div>
</div>




Notice that when you hover the text still shifts. The problem is that the padding is causes there to be less horizontal space in the element relative to the font-size, so there will be fewer characters per line and thus the text will shift. In larger paragraphs this shift is very noticeable and ugly from a UI standpoint.

You could center the text inside the element and use transform-origin: center, That might lead to the desired result. Otherwise you probably need extra nested elements. (I am really not sure what exactly you want, so I didn't add that to my snippet, since it might not be what you are looking for anyway...)

Please check this code we have using padding normal class remove for hover:


* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.pop-out {
  position: relative;
  transition: transform 0.2s ease-in-out, box-shadow 0.2s ease-in-out, background-color 0.2s ease-in-out, border-radius 0.2s ease-in-out, border 0.2s ease-in-out;
  /* Creating space between an element and its border */
  border-radius: 10px;
  border-left: 1rem solid transparent;
  border-right: 1rem solid transparent;
  &:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
    background-color: white !important;
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    transform: scale(1.1);
  }
}

#wrapper {
  margin-left: 50px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

#my-element {
  background-color: gray;
  width: 200px;
  flex: 0 0 auto;
}
<div id="wrapper">
  <div class="pop-out" id="my-element">
    My element.
  </div>
</div>




But one of the points in the question is that there is no padding on the non-hovered element. You have created an effect similar to padding with the border - I don't see that this solves the problem as set.

you want to need on hover with scale padding left and right,so I am modify
